# Deck.gl Column Layer not rendering on Samsung's latest devices with Chrome 120 (eg: S23, S22, Fold)

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl, deck.gl

**Description**
I am encountering a rendering issue with the Column Layer in deck.gl specifically on Samsung S23 and Fold devices. Upon opening a page containing the Column Layer, the browser becomes unresponsive, and the layer fails to render properly. Additionally, the example provided in deck.gl's documentation (deck.gl/docs/api-reference/layers/column-layer) also exhibits the same problem.

**Actual Behavior**
The browser becomes unresponsive, and the Column Layer fails to render as expected. I observed GLSL compilation errors in the fragment shader column-layer-fragment-shader-1.

**Github issue**: https://github.com/visgl/deck.gl/issues/8411

**Screenshots**
Breaking on S23 chrome:
[image]

Working on S23 Samsung browser:
[image]

**Expected Behavior**
The Column Layer should render correctly without causing the browser to freeze on Samsung S23 or Fold devices.

**Steps to Reproduce**
Visit https://deck.gl/docs/api-reference/layers/column-layer on Samsung's S23, S22 or Fold.

**Environment**
Framework version: 8.8.17
Browser: Chrome 120
OS: Android (Samsung)